# How to manually make queries into the DB using Django?

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

Sometimes, I have to make migrations that implie in loss of the db.

Then I have to manually go to the /admin page and re-insert every piece of data to start exploring my methods.

So, is there any way to manually insert data into the db when I create the models.Model classes?

(I'm using the default Django's db: sqlite)

Comment: You could save a copy of the database simply by making a copy of the sqlite3 file when it's in a known-good state. If something goes wrong, you have that copy to fall back on.

Comment: But I want to learn how to interact with the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use fixtures.
one time you insert all your data to database run this command

```
python manage.py dumpdata <app> > <file_path>.json
```

then store file in path

```
<any application>/fixtures/<fixture name>.json
```

after that you can load this data with command below

```
python manage.py loaddata <fixture name>
```

also you can write your own custom django migration to insert data like below

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import migrations


def create_countires(apps, schema_editor):
    Country = apps.get_model("app_name", "Country")
    Country.objects.bulk_create([
        Country(name="India"),
        Country(name="USA"),
    ])


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ...
        dependencies goes here
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_countires),
    ]
```

dependency must be last migration create country model. 
save this file on migration directory of any app and name it to format of migration files. by running **migration** command two country inserted to database.

Comment: I believe this should be exactly what I was looking for. Let me try it.. Thanks!